# GenerateUrl does not respect Localized Routes in Symfony4.4

Tags: php, symfony, routes, internationalization, symfony4

### Introduction

I am using: `Symfony v4.4.13` on `Windows 10 Pro` host (development machine).

In my project i am writing search module.

I have set *Localized Routes*: `en/ru`

### Requirement

I want to `switch locale` from *english* to *russian* if user inputs *search term in russian*.

### Problem

At the moment i get an error:

`No route found for "GET /ru/search/%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82" (from "https://127.0.0.1:8000/en/search")`

As seen in error - it happens because it does not translate `search` keyword to `поиск` keyword.

Only user's inputed `search term` is forwarded to next pageroute `goods_search`from `goods_search_no_term` and localized route is, seemingly, not taken into account.

The URL shoud be: `"/ru/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA/%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82"`

witch translates to utf8 `"/ru/поиск/тест"` instead of `"/ru/search/тест"!`

### Code

```
/**
 * @Route({
 *     "en": "/{_locale}/search",
 *     "ru": "/{_locale}/поиск"
 * }, name="goods_search_no_term", utf8=true)
 * @Route({
 *     "en": "/{_locale}/search/{term}",
 *     "ru": "/{_locale}/поиск/{term}"
 * }, name="goods_search", utf8=true)
 *
 * @param $term
 * @param Request $request
 * @param TranslatorInterface $translator
 * @param UltraHelpers $ultraHelpers
 * @return RedirectResponse|Response
 */
public function search(
    $term = '',
    Request $request,
    TranslatorInterface $translator,
    UltraHelpers $ultraHelpers
)
{
    if ($request->getMethod() === 'GET')
    {
        $term = $request->get('term');

        if (($term !== null) && ($term !== ''))
        {
            $lang = $request->getLocale();
            if ($lang === 'en')
            {
                if ($ultraHelpers->isRussianText($term))
                {
                    $link_redirect = $this->generateUrl('goods_search', ['_locale' => 'ru', 'term' => $term]);
                    return $this->redirect($link_redirect);
                }
                $search_items = $repo_item->searchEn($term);
            }
            elseif ($lang === 'ru')
            {
                $search_items = $repo_item->searchRu($term);
            }
        }

        return $this->render('search/search.html.twig',
            [
                'search_items' => null,
                'msg' => null,
                'term' => $term,
                'form' => $form->createView()
            ]
        );
    }
}

public function isRussianText($text)
{
    return preg_match('/[А-Яа-яЁё]/u', $text);
}
```

### Finally

Am i hitting a bug (edge case) or is it misconfiguration on my part?

Thank you for suggestions!

### Update 1

Note that fallback locale is set to `EN`

1. I open page `https://127.0.0.1:8000/en/search`;
2. Then in form search input field i enter text in russian: `тест` and hit enter;
3. I expect to be autmatically redirected to `russian locale` (as text is cyrillic) and get search results.
4. But i get `"/ru/SEARCH/тест"` instead of `"/ru/ПОИСК/тест"`!

### Update 2

```
$lang = $request->getLocale();
if ($lang === 'en')
{
    if ($ultraHelpers->isRussianText($term))
    {
        $link_redirect = $this->generateUrl('goods_search', ['_locale' => 'ru', 'term' => $term]);
        return $this->redirect($link_redirect);
    }
    $search_items = $repo_item->searchEn($term);
}
elseif ($lang === 'ru')
{
    $search_items = $repo_item->searchRu($term);
}
```

Comment: How do you request it in your app?

As I understand it, you still have to call the correct URLs tied to your controllers (either /en/search or /ru/поиск. If in your frontend app you call /ru/search, Symfony will obviously not know how to answer.

Comment: Described my workflow in update 1. URL is formed in the  backend (look at update 2). URL is modified to `set locale to ru` and add `search term` from GET.

Answer (score 0):

I have test it on a brand new project, and I think that I found the problem.

See the updated code : https://gist.github.com/Vin57/cbdd9ad4aac1d9b6b07d189902cf0cbb/d04beea090017f381132d3648b9cc128d8dc480b
You can see that I have modify the way you use and initialize `term` variable which is part of the problem.

Now I get this result :

```
[Web Server/PHP ] Sep 25 22:46:53 |INFO | SERVER GET  (302) /en/search/%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82
[Web Server/PHP ] Sep 25 22:46:59 |INFO | SERVER GET  (200) /ru/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA/%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82
```

But as you are using a form to submit input, I guess you want to pass variable into request. So I modify your code so it use request parameter : https://gist.github.com/Vin57/cbdd9ad4aac1d9b6b07d189902cf0cbb

I get this result :

```
[Web Server/PHP ] Sep 25 23:40:51 |INFO | SERVER GET  (302) /en/search?term=%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82
[Web Server/PHP ] Sep 25 23:40:58 |INFO | SERVER GET  (200) /ru/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA?term=%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82
```

Convert to UTF 8 it give :

```
[Web Server/PHP ] Sep 25 23:40:51 |INFO | SERVER GET  (302) https://127.0.0.1:8000/en/search?term=тест
[Web Server/PHP ] Sep 25 23:40:58 |INFO | SERVER GET  (200) https://127.0.0.1:8000/ru/поиск?term=тест
```

Comment: Hello, Vincent Phillipe. Thaks for your answer. Unfortunately 2 gists are identical. And you have set up `both routes` without `term`

Comment: You can check revision in the "revision" tab into gist.

Comment: Can you tell me if that work as you needed with the code I give ?

Comment: I have update my answer so the link rely to the correct revision.

Comment: Sorry, i have found the culprit an it was unlocalized AJAX call. Not a problem in backend.

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution !

Answer (score 0):

The error actually was in frontend. Ajax call was not localzied and always called URL for english locale.